# Tightvnc server on debian closes the connection when I open a program

Tags: vnc, debian

I installed TightVNC server on my Debian Wheezy machine. I'm using KDE. I'm able to connect to the server, but as soon as I click on any icon on the desktop of the server, the client loses the connection, and if I try to reconnect the server refuses the connection.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by installing vnc4server.