# Getting Tightvnc Server Working on Debian 8 (with KDE)

Tags: debian, vnc

I have done much research and attempted fixes on this issue, mostly involving tweaking the xstartup file. I've tried alternative VNC clients (UltraVNC and TightVNC) from a Windows 7 computer, with the same results for each client.

Basically, I get either a blank grey screen with only an arrow cursor, or a failure to connect at all.

I also tried a different VNC server (VNC4server) but abandoned that because, although I could connect, I got an error every time on the client window. And Tightvnc seems more widely used and user-supported.

I find that, almost regardless of what I put in the ~/.vnc/xstartup file (for example, even if it has just one line (startkde &) it will work if I specify "root" as the VNC user. But then I'm logged in as root and I need instead to follow standard *nix practice of being logged in as a non-root user. So, the issue does appear to relate to privileges. However, I check for correct ownership and executable flags on files after every time I edit them.

I read somewhere that the latest Tightvnc server will not allow KDE desktop to be started if there is already a desktop session running on the host (user logged in), so I start the host machine without anyone logged in. I have configured Tightvnc server as a service.

My current xstartup file follows, but like I said, I have already attempted many variants of these lines, commenting out nearly everything, from suggestions gathered on the internet.

> #!/bin/sh
>
> # Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
>   unset SESSION_MANAGER
>   exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc &
>      # unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
>
> [ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
>   [ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
>
> xsetroot -solid grey
>   vncconfig -iconic &
>   x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
>      # x-window-manager &
>   exec startkde &

Here is the service file, /lib/systemd/system/tightvncserver.service :

> [Unit]
>   Description=TightVNC remote desktop server
>   After=sshd.service
>
> [Service]
>   Type=dbus
>   ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver -geometry 1024x768 -depth 24 :1
>   User=vnc
>   Type=forking
>
> [Install]
>   WantedBy=multi-user.target

Here is the log after one reboot of the host followed by one connection attempt:

> 14/03/16 01:37:46 Xvnc version TightVNC-1.3.9
>   14/03/16 01:37:46 Copyright (C) 2000-2007 TightVNC Group
>   14/03/16 01:37:46 Copyright (C) 1999 AT&T Laboratories Cambridge
>   14/03/16 01:37:46 All Rights Reserved.
>   14/03/16 01:37:46 See http://www.tightvnc.com/ for information on TightVNC
>   14/03/16 01:37:46 Desktop name 'X' (test:1)
>   14/03/16 01:37:46 Protocol versions supported: 3.3, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7t, 3.8t
>   14/03/16 01:37:46 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 5901
>   /home/vnc/.vnc/xstartup: 12: /home/vnc/.vnc/xstartup: vncconfig: not found
>   x-terminal-emulator: Unknown option 'ls'.
>   x-terminal-emulator: Use --help to get a list of available command line options.
>   Error: cannot create directory "/tmp/ksocket-vncw1nXNU": File exists
>   startkde: Starting up...
>   kdeinit4: Aborting. bind() failed: Address already in use
>   Could not bind to socket '/tmp/ksocket-vncGcyXe4/kdeinit4__1'
>
> 14/03/16 01:38:09 Got connection from client 192.168.10.10
>   14/03/16 01:38:09 Using protocol version 3.8
>   14/03/16 01:38:14 Full-control authentication passed by 192.168.10.10
>   14/03/16 01:38:14 Pixel format for client 192.168.10.10:
>   14/03/16 01:38:14   32 bpp, depth 24, little endian
>   14/03/16 01:38:14   true colour: max r 255 g 255 b 255, shift r 16 g 8 b 0
>   14/03/16 01:38:14   no translation needed
>   14/03/16 01:38:14 Using hextile encoding for client 192.168.10.10
>   14/03/16 01:38:14 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 19
>   14/03/16 01:38:14 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 18
>   14/03/16 01:38:14 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 17
>   14/03/16 01:38:14 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 16
>   14/03/16 01:38:14 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 10
>   14/03/16 01:38:14 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 9
>   14/03/16 01:38:14 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 8
>   14/03/16 01:38:14 Using compression level 6 for client 192.168.10.10
>   14/03/16 01:38:14 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 192.168.10.10
>   14/03/16 01:38:14 Enabling cursor position updates for client 192.168.10.10
>   14/03/16 01:38:14 Using image quality level 6 for client 192.168.10.10
>   14/03/16 01:38:14 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -65530
>   14/03/16 01:38:14 Enabling LastRect protocol extension for client 192.168.10.10
>   14/03/16 01:38:14 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -223
>   14/03/16 01:38:14 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -32768
>   14/03/16 01:38:14 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -32767
>   14/03/16 01:38:14 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -32764
>   14/03/16 01:38:14 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -32766
>   14/03/16 01:38:14 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -32765
>   14/03/16 01:38:14 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -1063131698
>   14/03/16 01:38:43 Client 192.168.10.10 gone
>   14/03/16 01:38:43 Statistics:
>   14/03/16 01:38:43   key events received 0, pointer events 260
>   14/03/16 01:38:43   framebuffer updates 2, rectangles 5, bytes 776789
>   14/03/16 01:38:43     cursor shape updates 2, bytes 4920
>   14/03/16 01:38:43     cursor position updates 1, bytes 12
>   14/03/16 01:38:43     hextile rectangles 2, bytes 771857
>   14/03/16 01:38:43   raw bytes equivalent 6291480, compression ratio 8.151095

Any ideas?

[EDIT, 2014/03/14, 1409 UTC]: I forgot to mention that I had it working error-free with XFCE desktop. But I much prefer KDE, and I wish to get that working if at all possible.

[EDIT, 2014/03/14, 2216 UTC]: This is a follow-up to Paul H.'s suggestion, I'm putting it here because the mini-formatting of comments doesn't seem to allow blockquotes and images.

Thank you, that got me further. After I give the "startkde &" command, the client window opens with a sensible-looking desktop that is starting to load and gets this far before closing (note the error message in top left):

[image: Notice the error message in top left]

The log is as follows:

> 14/03/16 21:32:11 Desktop name 'X' (test:1)
>   14/03/16 21:32:11 Protocol versions supported: 3.3, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7t, 3.8t
>   14/03/16 21:32:11 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 5901
>   QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
>   QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
>
> 14/03/16 21:32:37 Got connection from client 192.168.10.10
>   14/03/16 21:32:37 Using protocol version 3.8
>   14/03/16 21:32:47 Full-control authentication passed by 192.168.10.10
>   14/03/16 21:32:47 Pixel format for client 192.168.10.10:
>   14/03/16 21:32:47   32 bpp, depth 24, little endian
>   14/03/16 21:32:47   true colour: max r 255 g 255 b 255, shift r 16 g 8 b 0
>   14/03/16 21:32:47   no translation needed
>   14/03/16 21:32:47 Using hextile encoding for client 192.168.10.10
>   14/03/16 21:32:47 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 19
>   14/03/16 21:32:47 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 18
>   14/03/16 21:32:47 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 17
>   14/03/16 21:32:47 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 16
>   14/03/16 21:32:47 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 10
>   14/03/16 21:32:47 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 9
>   14/03/16 21:32:47 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 8
>   14/03/16 21:32:47 Using compression level 6 for client 192.168.10.10
>   14/03/16 21:32:47 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 192.168.10.10
>   14/03/16 21:32:47 Enabling cursor position updates for client 192.168.10.10
>   14/03/16 21:32:47 Using image quality level 6 for client 192.168.10.10
>   14/03/16 21:32:47 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -65530
>   14/03/16 21:32:47 Enabling LastRect protocol extension for client 192.168.10.10
>   14/03/16 21:32:47 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -223
>   14/03/16 21:32:47 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -32768
>   14/03/16 21:32:47 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -32767
>   14/03/16 21:32:47 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -32764
>   14/03/16 21:32:47 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -32766
>   14/03/16 21:32:47 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -32765
>   14/03/16 21:32:47 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -1063131698
>   Connecting to deprecated signal QDBusConnectionInterface::serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString)
>   QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
>   QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
>   kbuildsycoca4 running...
>   kbuildsycoca4(989) KBuildSycoca::checkTimestamps: checking file timestamps
>   kbuildsycoca4(989) KBuildSycoca::checkTimestamps: timestamps check ok
>   kbuildsycoca4(989) kdemain: Emitting notifyDatabaseChanged ()
>   QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
>   QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
>   Object::connect: No such signal org::freedesktop::UPower::DeviceAdded(QString)
>   Object::connect: No such signal org::freedesktop::UPower::DeviceRemoved(QString)
>   QDBusConnection: name 'org.freedesktop.UDisks2' had owner '' but we thought it was ':1.11'
>   klauncher: Exiting on signal 15
>   knotify4: Fatal IO error: client killed
>   kded4: Fatal IO error: client killed
>   konsole: Fatal IO error: client killed
>   konsole(902) Konsole::SessionManager::~SessionManager: Konsole SessionManager destroyed with sessions still alive

The first error message, ending with "application may misbehave," is supposed to be unimportant, from the bug reports I have seen. The rest, I'm not sure about..

Answer (score 0):

KDE works with tightvncserver on my system. Try this xstartup:

```
#!/bin/sh
unset SESSION_MANAGER 
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
konsole &
```

You should get a terminal window when you connect thru VNC. Then try `startkde &` from the terminal and see if it starts. If it doesn't, note what the error messages are in the terminal and go from there. If it does start, you can try adding `startkde &` to the end of the xstartup script and try again.

Here is a minimal xstartup that worked for me using vnc4server and xfce. You can add `konsole &` like before and change `xfce4-session &` to `startkde &`. I haven't tried it with KDE.

```
#!/bin/sh

unset SESSION_MANAGER
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
xfce4-session &
```

Comment: I added an edit to the question, describing what happened after following your suggestion.

Comment: I added unset SESSION_MANAGER to the xstartup. I don't know if this will have any affect, but it is suggested in the default xstartup file for normal desktop so it is worth a try to see if any of the error messages change. Otherwise, hopefully someone with more knowledge will be able to point you in the right direction for the errors you are getting.

Comment: I put it in but had the same result.

Comment: So I still have the fault. The answer I received helped a bit with troubleshooting. Does anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: I have now tried it on a fresh install of Debian 8 (KDE), using both the default xstartup and the one given by Paul H, using no service but just giving the command "tightvncserver -geometry 1024x768 -depth 24". It just dies on connection, as above, or refuses connection.

Comment: Still getting the same errors in the log as before?  You can try looking thru other log files, such as messages and see if there are any other errors being logged at the same time that aren't being logged in the vnc log file. And just to be sure, KDE is working fine when not using VNC, correct? I saw another post [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/124568/152238) with a similar situation which was solved by using vnc4server. I'll add a minimal xstartup to my answer for vnc4server that worked for me with xfce..

Comment: At this point, I'm a bit "logged out", so to speak, and have to catch up with other work. I tried vnc4server before and had on-client error messages. When I get back to this project I'll be compiling Tigervnc server. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Also, I had tightvnc server working with xfce but I need to be able to use KDE, another reason to try some other vnc server.

Comment: @rvenner If you are open to something besides VNC, you can try using [NX](https://www.nomachine.com/)  instead. You will need to download the [.deb package](https://www.nomachine.com/download/linux&id=1) and install, as it is not part of the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Replace sddm to xdm fix the black screen problem, and it works well for me now, refert to this:
https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/532320-vncserver-blank-screen

```
Switch your Display Manager to XDM, KDM (you would have to install that in Yast, first), or LightDM on the machines you are trying to access.

Code:
su -
and give the password, then:
Code:
update-alternatives --config default-displaymanager
choose your Display Manager from the list.

SDDM does not work well with VNC yet.
```