# MacOS screen sharing app to control Debian host using (x11)vnc

Tags: debian, ssh, vnc, macos, x11vnc

My goal is to connect to a remote host (running Debian) such that I can control the whole desktop environment. So I tried using the vnc/x11vnc as indicated in these posts:

- [How to connect to x11vnc server on Linux from OS X (macOS)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/356569/how-to-connect-to-x11vnc-server-on-linux-from-os-x-macos)
- [Getting Tightvnc Server Working on Debian 8 (with KDE)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269600/getting-tightvnc-server-working-on-debian-8-with-kde)

When I want to connect, I invoke this in the Debian host:

```
❯ x11vnc -rfbauth ~/.vnc/passwd
12/05/2021 06:01:16 passing arg to libvncserver: -rfbauth
12/05/2021 06:01:16 passing argx to libvncserver: /home/massisenergy/.vnc/passwd
12/05/2021 06:01:16 x11vnc version: 0.9.13 lastmod: 2011-08-10  pid: 3011
12/05/2021 06:01:16 XOpenDisplay("") failed.
12/05/2021 06:01:16 Trying again with XAUTHLOCALHOSTNAME=localhost ...
12/05/2021 06:01:16
12/05/2021 06:01:16 *** XOpenDisplay failed. No -display or DISPLAY.
12/05/2021 06:01:16 *** Trying ":0" in 4 seconds.  Press Ctrl-C to abort.
12/05/2021 06:01:16 *** 1 2 3 4
12/05/2021 06:01:20 *** XOpenDisplay of ":0" successful.
12/05/2021 06:01:20
12/05/2021 06:01:20 Using X display :0
12/05/2021 06:01:20 rootwin: 0x143 reswin: 0x2400001 dpy: 0xc74adb40
12/05/2021 06:01:20
12/05/2021 06:01:20 ------------------ USEFUL INFORMATION ------------------
12/05/2021 06:01:20 X DAMAGE available on display, using it for polling hints.
12/05/2021 06:01:20   To disable this behavior use: '-noxdamage'
12/05/2021 06:01:20
12/05/2021 06:01:20   Most compositing window managers like 'compiz' or 'beryl'
12/05/2021 06:01:20   cause X DAMAGE to fail, and so you may not see any screen
12/05/2021 06:01:20   updates via VNC.  Either disable 'compiz' (recommended) or
12/05/2021 06:01:20   supply the x11vnc '-noxdamage' command line option.
12/05/2021 06:01:20
12/05/2021 06:01:20 Wireframing: -wireframe mode is in effect for window moves.
12/05/2021 06:01:20   If this yields undesired behavior (poor response, painting
12/05/2021 06:01:20   errors, etc) it may be disabled:
12/05/2021 06:01:20    - use '-nowf' to disable wireframing completely.
12/05/2021 06:01:20    - use '-nowcr' to disable the Copy Rectangle after the
12/05/2021 06:01:20      moved window is released in the new position.
12/05/2021 06:01:20   Also see the -help entry for tuning parameters.
12/05/2021 06:01:20   You can press 3 Alt_L's (Left "Alt" key) in a row to
12/05/2021 06:01:20   repaint the screen, also see the -fixscreen option for
12/05/2021 06:01:20   periodic repaints.
12/05/2021 06:01:20
12/05/2021 06:01:20 XFIXES available on display, resetting cursor mode
12/05/2021 06:01:20   to: '-cursor most'.
12/05/2021 06:01:20   to disable this behavior use: '-cursor arrow'
12/05/2021 06:01:20   or '-noxfixes'.
12/05/2021 06:01:20 using XFIXES for cursor drawing.
12/05/2021 06:01:20 GrabServer control via XTEST.
12/05/2021 06:01:20
12/05/2021 06:01:20 Scroll Detection: -scrollcopyrect mode is in effect to
12/05/2021 06:01:20   use RECORD extension to try to detect scrolling windows
12/05/2021 06:01:20   (induced by either user keystroke or mouse input).
12/05/2021 06:01:20   If this yields undesired behavior (poor response, painting
12/05/2021 06:01:20   errors, etc) it may be disabled via: '-noscr'
12/05/2021 06:01:20   Also see the -help entry for tuning parameters.
12/05/2021 06:01:20   You can press 3 Alt_L's (Left "Alt" key) in a row to
12/05/2021 06:01:20   repaint the screen, also see the -fixscreen option for
12/05/2021 06:01:20   periodic repaints.
12/05/2021 06:01:20
12/05/2021 06:01:20 XKEYBOARD: number of keysyms per keycode 7 is greater
12/05/2021 06:01:20   than 4 and 51 keysyms are mapped above 4.
12/05/2021 06:01:20   Automatically switching to -xkb mode.
12/05/2021 06:01:20   If this makes the key mapping worse you can
12/05/2021 06:01:20   disable it with the "-noxkb" option.
12/05/2021 06:01:20   Also, remember "-remap DEAD" for accenting characters.
12/05/2021 06:01:20
12/05/2021 06:01:20 X FBPM extension not supported.
12/05/2021 06:01:20 X display is capable of DPMS.
12/05/2021 06:01:20 --------------------------------------------------------
12/05/2021 06:01:20
12/05/2021 06:01:20 Default visual ID: 0x21
12/05/2021 06:01:20 Read initial data from X display into framebuffer.
12/05/2021 06:01:20 initialize_screen: fb_depth/fb_bpp/fb_Bpl 24/32/7680
12/05/2021 06:01:20
12/05/2021 06:01:20 X display :0 is 32bpp depth=24 true color
12/05/2021 06:01:20
12/05/2021 06:01:20 Autoprobing TCP port
12/05/2021 06:01:20 Autoprobing selected TCP port 5900
12/05/2021 06:01:20 Autoprobing TCP6 port
12/05/2021 06:01:20 Autoprobing selected TCP6 port 5900
12/05/2021 06:01:20 listen6: bind: Address already in use
12/05/2021 06:01:20 Not listening on IPv6 interface.
12/05/2021 06:01:20
12/05/2021 06:01:20 Xinerama is present and active (e.g. multi-head).
12/05/2021 06:01:20 Xinerama: number of sub-screens: 1
12/05/2021 06:01:20 Xinerama: no blackouts needed (only one sub-screen)
12/05/2021 06:01:20
12/05/2021 06:01:20 fb read rate: 3248 MB/sec
12/05/2021 06:01:20 fast read: reset -wait  ms to: 10
12/05/2021 06:01:20 fast read: reset -defer ms to: 10
12/05/2021 06:01:20 The X server says there are 20 mouse buttons.
12/05/2021 06:01:20 screen setup finished.
12/05/2021 06:01:20

The VNC desktop is:      debianSR:0
PORT=5900

******************************************************************************
Have you tried the x11vnc '-ncache' VNC client-side pixel caching feature yet?

The scheme stores pixel data offscreen on the VNC viewer side for faster
retrieval.  It should work with any VNC viewer.  Try it by running:

    x11vnc -ncache 10 ...

One can also add -ncache_cr for smooth 'copyrect' window motion.
More info: http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/faq.html#faq-client-caching

12/05/2021 06:01:23 Got connection from client 10.39.3.163
12/05/2021 06:01:23   other clients:
12/05/2021 06:01:23 Normal socket connection
12/05/2021 06:01:23 Disabled X server key autorepeat.
12/05/2021 06:01:23   to force back on run: 'xset r on' (3 times)
12/05/2021 06:01:23 incr accepted_client=1 for 10.39.3.163:57928  sock=11
12/05/2021 06:01:23 Client Protocol Version 3.3
12/05/2021 06:01:23 Protocol version sent 3.3, using 3.3
12/05/2021 06:01:23 created   xdamage object: 0x2400040
12/05/2021 06:01:23 client useCopyRect: 10.39.3.163 0
12/05/2021 06:01:23 client_set_net: 10.39.3.163  0.0035
12/05/2021 06:01:24 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0x000003F3)
12/05/2021 06:01:24 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0x000003EA)
12/05/2021 06:01:24 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 10.39.3.163
12/05/2021 06:01:24 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0x00000450)
12/05/2021 06:01:24 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0x0000044C)
12/05/2021 06:01:24 Enabling NewFBSize protocol extension for client 10.39.3.163
12/05/2021 06:01:24 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0x0000044D)
12/05/2021 06:01:24 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0x00000451)
12/05/2021 06:01:24 Using zlib encoding for client 10.39.3.163
12/05/2021 06:01:24 Pixel format for client 10.39.3.163:
12/05/2021 06:01:24   32 bpp, depth 32, little endian
12/05/2021 06:01:24   true colour: max r 255 g 255 b 255, shift r 16 g 8 b 0
12/05/2021 06:01:24 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0x000003F3)
12/05/2021 06:01:24 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0x000003EA)
12/05/2021 06:01:24 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 10.39.3.163
12/05/2021 06:01:24 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0x00000450)
12/05/2021 06:01:24 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0x0000044C)
12/05/2021 06:01:24 Enabling NewFBSize protocol extension for client 10.39.3.163
12/05/2021 06:01:24 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0x0000044D)
12/05/2021 06:01:24 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0x00000451)
12/05/2021 06:01:24 Switching from zlib to zlib Encoding for client 10.39.3.163
12/05/2021 06:01:25 client 1 network rate 386.8 KB/sec (5119.8 eff KB/sec)
12/05/2021 06:01:25 client 1 latency:  0.5 ms
12/05/2021 06:01:25 dt1: 1.6203, dt2: 0.0000 dt3: 0.0005 bytes: 626674
12/05/2021 06:01:25 link_rate: LR_LAN - 1 ms, 386 KB/s
12/05/2021 06:01:26 copy_tiles: allocating first_line at size 61
12/05/2021 06:01:33 created selwin: 0x2400041
12/05/2021 06:01:33 called initialize_xfixes()
12/05/2021 06:01:39 client_count: 0
12/05/2021 06:01:39 Restored X server key autorepeat to: 1
12/05/2021 06:01:39 viewer exited.
12/05/2021 06:01:39 deleted 60 tile_row polling images.
```

But after sometime (maybe 2 mins, maybe 2 hours), it stops, which I don't know why. If I start it again, then works again for some time. Any idea what is going on/ how can I make a more reliable & long lasting (~upto 8 hours at a stretch) vnc connection?

This is my `startup` file:

```
❯ cat ~/.vnc/xstartup
#!/bin/zsh

# unset SESSION_MANAGER

xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
startxfce4 &
/etc/X11/Xsession
```

1. Any suggestions for other ways to connect (such as [Xpra](https://github.com/Xpra-org/xpra/tree/master/docs/Usage), which I'm considering now) are also welcome!
2. I am unable to utilise the bidirectional clipboard (it's greyed out in the `Screen Sharing.app`). Need to change any settings in the Debian host for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two alternatives:

- [X2Go](https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php)
  It's a great remote desktop solution, actually the only one I could find where keyboard layout switching worked correctly (in case you use multiple key layouts). X2Go server is available on Debian repos; you'll need its own client, there is a Mac version.
- [xrdp](http://xrdp.org/)
  This also works quite well; it essentially starts a Microsoft Terminal Server / RDS protocol. it's also available in Debian repos. For the client side, you need a Microsoft RDS protocol client; there is an official from MS I think and others also.

The above solutions provide 2-way clipboard.

I've used `Xpra` for remote **application** access; it was faster than X forwarding. I haven't used it for remote desktop.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `x11vnc` and `tightvnc` at the same time. They work completely differently. `x11vnc` allows for remote access to an exsisting REAL X server, while `tightvnc` creates a new, hidden X server that VNC clients access.

I assume you want to use `x11vnc` as that is the command that you run. In that case please remove the `tightvncserver` package and `~/.vnc/xstartup`, as `xstartup` is only used for `tightvnc`.

Also, when you start the `x11vnc` server, start it from within the exsisting X session, so that the $DISPLAY variable is set properly.

Depending on your desktop environment you may be able to find an application called "X11VNC Server" that starts `x11vnc` in GUI mode, to allow you to configure it easily.

To have it start automatically, add it to your .xinitrc if you're using xinit. If you're using a Display Manager, see [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/653221/how-can-i-set-up-x11vnc-to-start-on-boot-with-lightdm/653222#653222).